# Custom Annotation with AOP is affecting GetMapping annotation

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I implemented a custom annotation with AOP to add on additional behavior. The usage is something as follows:

```
@GetMapping(path="/my/path/{date}/{text}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public String subscribe(@PathVariable String date, @PathVariable String text, @PermittedMarkets String[] marketCodes) { //do processing and return something here }
```

and my Annotation and AOP are as follows:

```
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PermittedMarkets {

}

@Aspect
@Component
public class MarketsAspect {
    @Value("#{${config.market.permitted.marketmapping:{:}}}")
    private Map<String, String> roleToMarketCodeMap;
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active:}")
    private String profile;

    @Around("execution(* *(.., @com.org.app.service.security.annotation.PermittedMarkets (*), ..))")
    public void permittedMarkets(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        final var args = pjp.getArgs();
        final var annotations = ((MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature()).getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();

        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            for (Annotation annotation : annotations[i]) {
                if (annotation.annotationType() == PermittedMarkets.class) {
                    if (profile.equals("dev")) { args[i] = "*"; continue; }
                    final var grantedAuthorities = Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication())
                            .map(Authentication::getAuthorities)
                            .orElseThrow(() -> new AccessDeniedException("No authorities found"));

                    args[i] = grantedAuthorities.stream()
                            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                            .filter(entitlement -> entitlement.contains("app_user"))
                            .map(A_entitlement -> roleToMarketCodeMap.get(A_entitlement))
                            .filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
                }
            }
        }
        pjp.proceed(args);
    }
}
```

However, I found out that this does not seem to work as intended. When I comment out the entirety of permittedMarkets() method, the frontend response has this Response Header:

[image]

If I do not comment out, it has this response header and error log:

[image]

[image]
EventSource's response has a Content-Type specifying an unsupported type: -. Aborting connection

It seems that the AOP I added is affecting the GetMapping on my original method. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You have an `@Around` aspect that returns `void`. Which effectively now makes the methods always return `null`. Always return `Object` and always return the result of the call to `joinpoint.proceed()` else you will break things.

Comment: Can I ask how will this affect the GetMapping, or is it that whatever that breaks due to not returning the result is "random"?

Comment: It isn't random anything that gets proxied is affected. Basically your aspect is wrong, never use `void` for the around aspect, always return the result of `proceed()`, you never know what might be the actual return type.

Comment: you're right! I just took a look at other AOP examples which use around() quite a few of them return Object and the result of proceed(), just that the one I referenced while coding this returned void, and I copied that without knowing its effects.

Comment: yup! it works perfectly fine now. Which is weird, because I distinctly recall it worked last week, but only this week it started throwing errors, so thats why it seemed random to me

Comment: M. Deinum is 99% right. But of course, an around advice can return `void`, if its pointcut only targets `void` methods. It is only a problem for non-void ones.